# Opinion about migrate and use 2 tables on Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a reservation system. Until now, I did the reservation table and check for the availability using this model:

```
class Reservations < ActiveRecord::Base
# User_id 
# Room_id
# Start_date
# End_date
# Day (integer)
# isCanceled (false automatically)

belongs_to :user, :class_name => "Users", :foreign_key => "user_id"
belongs_to :room, :class_name => "Rooms", :foreign_key => "room_id"
end
```

Now I want to add a "Music lessons" table to fetch and add the courses that repeats every day. This is my model:

```
class Roomschedule < ActiveRecord::Base
# Name
# Start_date
# End_date
# Room_id 
# Day (integer)

belongs_to :room, :class_name => "Rooms", :foreign_key => "room_id"
end
```

In my Reservations controller, I display all my programs using this sql query:

```
@all = Reservations.where("start_date > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day).order("start_date ASC")
```

But I want to merge Reservations table with Roomschedule table to also check and display with the current ongoing courses.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an inner join:

```
@current_courses = Reservations.joins(:roomschedule).where("end_date < Time.now && start_date > Time.now").order("start_date ASC")
```

Updated:

```
day_index = Date.today.strftime("%u") # or %w depending on your index
@todays_courses = Reservations.joins(:roomschedule).where(day: day_index).order("start_date ASC")
```

Comment: In Roomschedule model, Day is an integer from 0 to 6, as an index of weekdays. How can I make roomschedule to repeat every week? For example, in day 0 (monday) there is a studio session between start_date and end_date intervals. I want it to repeat every week.

Comment: Updated my answer. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Actually, I don't want the todays_courses but the weeks_courses included in the same table with Reservations